# JQuery select based on the FIRST in a string of classes

Tags: jquery

I've got two elements which are the basis of a small tab script. For various reasons (called Internet Exploder 6) I've had to build it like this:

**Tab headers**

```
<span class="Block1 inactive" id="Tab1">Label1</span>
<span class="Block2 inactive" id="Tab2">Label2</span>
<span class="Block3 inactive" id="Tab3">Label3</span>
```

**Tab contents**

```
<div class="contents inactive" id="Block1 ">Stuff here</div>
<div class="contents inactive" id="Block2 ">Stuff here</div>
<div class="contents inactive" id="Block3 ">Stuff here</div>
```

So when Tab1 is clicked my script needs to get class of "Block1" and then search for the div with the matching class or ID.

But how can I select for the first class in a set of multiple classes? Is there anything along these lines? Is this even possible?

```
var tabtoshow = $(this).attr('class':first);
var tabtoshow = $(this).attr('class:first');
var tabtoshow = $(this).attr('class[0]');
```

Stuck...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any solution that's any prettier than this:

```
var tabtoshow = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```

... the relative order of the classes are generally not intended to carry any significance, so I don't think there are any helpers for that.

Comment: I'd recommend .split(/\s+/) to sort the problem of having multiple spaces

Comment: @Jon: doesn't really affect anything when looking for the first class, but sure.

Comment: True :) I shouldn't program paranoid!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way of doing this without having to split or worry about spaces

```
<span class="inactive" id="Tab1"><a href="#Block1">Label1</a></span>
```

then to grab the correct div to show

```
var tabtoshow = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the headers match the divs in number and order, and they are children of some parent without other siblings, you might be able to make use of the jQuery [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

```
var tabtoshow = $('.contents').eq($(this).index());
```

or

```
var tabtoshow = $('#Block' + ($(this).index() + 1));
```

(Note that here `tabtoshow` is a jquery object.)